# How do I change Oceania to Austrailia on the google maps?

Tags: angular, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using google Maps API with Angular, and when I zoom out all the way I see this:

[image: Image here]

this is supposed to say "Australia" instead of Oceania. Is there a way we can change that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well first you want to set the Map Center to Australia

So something like:  `const center = { lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044 };`

Also you can set the bounds restrictions.
Then set the Zoom level so sreen fits the entire country.

So JS code will look something like this:

```
const center = { lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044 };
const zoom = 4;

this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapDiv.nativeElement, {
    center: center,
    zoom: zoom,

    minZoom: zoom - 3,
    maxZoom: zoom + 3,

    disableDefaultUI: true,
    restriction: {
      latLngBounds: {
        north: -10,
        south: -40,
        east: 160,
        west: 100,
      },
    },
});
```

You will just have to play around with the zoom, center, restriction values to fit your needs.

Documentation for this is here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/interaction

Comment: I didn't center the map on Australia, because of the requirements I had (I had to center the map on Louisiana, US) but setting minZoom and maxZoom in setOptions worked the way I wanted it to.